# How should i return a json value into another method

Tags: java, arrays, json, object

I am fetching an JSON response from an API. 
I should return those JSON response to another method.

```
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build(); 
    HttpGet request=new HttpGet("/2.0/clusters/list");
    request.addHeader("Authorization",bearerToken); 
    request.addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache"); 
    HttpResponse response=client.execute(request); 
    System.out.println("Response Code:" +   
    response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    String json = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    System.out.println("Gather Details\n"); 
    JSONObject cluster = new JSONObject(json); 
    JSONArray array=cluster.getJSONArray("clusters");
    for (int i=0;i< array.length();i++)
    {
    JSONObject clusters = array.getJSONObject(i); 
    String id=clusters.get("id").toString(); 
    String time=clusters.get("time").toString();
    System.out.println("Id:"+id+"time:"+time+"\n");

    if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()!=200) {
    System.out.println("Failed HTTP 
    response"+response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()+" "+json);
              }
    return json;

/*Another method which takes json values and insert into db*/

    public void insertdb(JSONObject json) throws Exception{
    Connection con = ConnectToDB(); 
    String tablename="Cluster_Info";
    JSONObject cluster = new JSONObject(json); 
    System.out.println(cluster);
    JSONArray array=cluster.getJSONArray("clusters");
```

Help me out to send the json response to other method to insert into database.

Comment: What is wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure your insertdb method takes a JSONObject as parameter? seems like it should be taking a json String, because it converts the input parameter  into a JSONObject

Comment: can you share the code where you are persisting the jsonobject?

Comment: if you want to do this for your all API then I would suggest you to add interceptor or Filter for this specific task. You can use it as pre or post processing of your API.

Answer (score 0):

- use gson-2.1.jar or later.
- just create POJO(Gather) with ID and Time Fields(with getter/setter)
- Add another class with List items like below

  ```
  public class GatherDetails{private List<Gather> items;}
  ```
- Add the below line of conversion in main 1'st method.

  ```
  HttpResponse response=client.execute(request);
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  GatherDetails gatherDetails= gson.fromJson(response.getEntity(), GatherDetails.class);
  ```

now gatherDetails have a list of objects.Edit the second method like below.

```
public void insertdb(GatherDetails gatherDetails) throws Exception{
for(Gather gather:GatherDetails.items){
gather.getId();gather.getTime();
//insert logic goes here
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the type of `insertdb` method parameter to `String`, and then parse it to `JSONObject` in your method.

```
/*Another method which takes json values and insert into db*/

public void insertdb(String jsonString) throws Exception{
// parse object
JSONObject json = JSONObject.parseObject(jsonString);

Connection con = ConnectToDB(); 
String tablename="Cluster_Info";
JSONObject cluster = new JSONObject(json); 
System.out.println(cluster);
JSONArray array=cluster.getJSONArray("clusters");
```